# Why does my executable's .dynstr contain symbols from statically linked libraries?

Tags: c++, g++, static-linking

I'm building a C++ executable. I'm statically linking several of the C and C++ libraries I'm using, including a custom one. (I am not, however, statically linking every library I'm using.)

Even taking that into account, the executable seemed abnormally large. I used `objdump -h`, which told me that I was using far more space in `.dynstr` than I expected. I've compiled with `-Os` and run `strip`, but when I run

```
$ readelf -p .dynstr slamshift
```

I get many entries like

```
  [ 13588]  _ZN3yuu6windowC2Ev
  [ 1359b]  _ZTSN3yuu7gfx_ctxE
  [ 135ae]  _ZN4YAML7Scanner11ScanFlowEndEv
  [ 135ce]  __glewVertexFormatNV
```

for symbols in the libraries I've statically linked (my own library, yaml-cpp, and GLEW).

Why are these symbols appearing in my executable? If I've statically linked the libraries involved, shouldn't the symbol names be unnecessary?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, GCC 4.6.3, and CMake and its default settings to build, if those are relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why are these symbols appearing in my executable?

There are only two reasons for these symbols to be exported from your executable and appear in the dynamic symbol table.

1. You linked your executable with `--export-dynamic` (aka `-E`) linker flag, or
2. Some other shared library participating in the link references these symbols.

If you are doing #1, the answer is simple: don't do it.

If you got the symbols exported because of #2, you really want the symbols to be exported, otherwise the code will likely fail elsewhere.

Comment: Indeed, the problem turned out to be CMake including -rdynamic by default and that apparently takes precedence over most other linker flags.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little-known fact that ELF executables can be opened as dynamic objects using dl_open and friends. For that to work they need to have symbol exports. I think that is what is happening here.

You could try doing the final program link using `--exclude-libs ALL` to the linker. It would look like `-Wl,--exclude-libs ALL` on the gcc command line.
*Update: this results in symbols still existing, but marked as Hidden.*

You might also try `-Wl,--exclude-all-symbols`.
*Update: I was wrong about this one. It is for PE targets only.*

I tried this and it worked:
`gcc -static -Wl,-s export-test.c`